# Conditional ImageURL asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageurl

I have a table with values

```
ID     PicURL            FilePath
1      www.a.com/1.png   NULL
2      NULL              ~/Images/2.jpeg
```

In code behind I have

```
<asp:Image ID="imageControl" runat="server" Width="100" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>'></asp:Image>
```

How do I include the case when FilePath is null and ImageURL has to get value from PicURL?

Thanks
Rashmi

Comment: What part of the code is reading the table? Isn't there a SQL query someplace?

Comment: Is it always the case that one or the other is null? What if both are populated? Assuming FilePath takes precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change data structure, or query... and want to do it in code front, you can do it like this (though it's cleaner to do in ItemDataBound):

```
<asp:Image ID="imageControl" runat="server" Width="100" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") != null ? Eval("FilePath") : Eval("PicURL")  %>'></asp:Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a calculated field/property and do the logic there and then bind that property?

Comment: Would probably belong in the comments section, rather than in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your SQL Query to return either PicURL or FilePath based on whichever value is not null. You can reverse the order of the field list depending on which field should take precedence.

`SELECT Id, Isnull(PicURL, FilePath) as ImageUrl from tblImage`

```
<asp:Image ID="imageControl" runat="server" 
Width="100" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl")%>'></asp:Image>
```